# How to set default language for bibliography using ugost2008ls style and XeLaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, xetex

I'm using XeLaTeX+BibTeX. Is there any way to make all autogenerated words like "access mode", "vol", etc appear in Russian without manually specifying `language={russian}` for every item in `.bib` file?

Say, the MCVE below is rendered to this:

[image]

Note that the header is in Russian (so probably a language is somehow specified already), as well as "access mode" words for the second reference.

MCVE contains two files:

`test.tex` (should be in UTF-8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}
Ссылки~\cite{a, b}.

\bibliographystyle{ugost2008ls}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

And `test.bib`:

```
@unpublished(a,
  name = {Some Title A},
  url = {http://example.com/a},
)
@unpublished(b,
  name = {Some Title B},
  url = {http://example.com/b},
  language = {russian},
)
```

Compilation command:

```
xelatex test.tex  && bibtex test && xelatex test.tex && xelatex test.tex
```

Comment: After looking in the `bst` file and in its documentation, I'm afraid you cannot do it; the doc is very specific in saying that the default language is English and that one *has* to add `language={russian}` for localizing an entry.

Comment: @egreg that's kind of sad to hear. Thank you for your effort!